# Sketch3 | Is it possible to create a text table?

Tags: text, sketch-app, tables

*Just a super simple text table...*
[image]

I'm fairly new to Sketch, and I'm sure I haven't cracked even a quarter of what can be done with the program. So I wasn't very surprised when I realized I have no idea how to make a table.

I searched through the application, as well as Sketch resources online, and I *am* surprised to see that it may not be possible! I haven't even seen anyone bring the T word up in the same sentence as Sketch. Is it possible that a web design application wouldn't have tools for one of the most basic HTML elements? Or am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: One of the ways Sketch frustrates me with its immaturity >_<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no functionality for making tables per se, but with a combination of symbols and a plugin called  [stack children](https://github.com/cemre/cemre-sketch-plugins) you might be able to make tables easier.
It doesn't automatically generate a grid like your example, but if you create a symbol out of a row of the table, the plugin will help you align them one under the other.

[image]

Comment: What a neat plug-in! Shame there's no built-in functionality for this, but thank you for confirming.

Comment: Since Sketch 3.7 this is a built-in feature: https://blog.sketchapp.com/sketch-3-7-and-new-symbols-d833a5be4027#.kehu4bh2d

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try [Sketch Data Studio](http://thetylerwolf.github.io/sketch-data-studio/). It's a plugin that makes converting data into data tables quick and easy.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please be careful when posting link only answers.  Some could consider the answer as spam and downvote your answer.  Also, please be advised when you make an answer with a link only over time that link or in this case the plugin could no longer be supported so we will have to remove your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use Keynote to quickly create tables (and charts as well) - style them there and then copy/paste to Sketch. Not the best possible solution, but it works for prototyping phase - see more details [in this blog post](https://ejla.github.io/2015/11/01/sketch-and-keynote-love-each-other.html)

Comment: Hi mirna, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

You can copy and paste table grids from Excel or Apple Numbers into Sketch. Although, if you plan to resize the table in Sketch, the text either won't increase in size (Apple Numbers, Excel) or it might go out of line with the grid (Excel). So I'd use Excel/Apple Numbers just to get a nice grid going, paste that into Sketch and then start creating my text in Sketch, afterwards using the alignment tools as needed to get everything lined up in the cells.