# How to insert a table in Sketch 3?

Tags: sketch-app

I want to insert a 1*12 table in Sketch 3 artboard. But I'm not able to find out how to insert it.

I've already read this [article](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54819/sketch3-is-it-possible-to-create-a-text-table). But according to the answer, the plugin is used to distribute the items. I need a "real" table which has borders.

Could someone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using illustrator, exporting the table and contents into Sketch? There is no table tool which I'm aware of. Sketch it's definitely lacking some features, however this tv isn't one I've ever needed. When making tables, say a data table or returned search results, I use a rectangle, and to make the borders I use the shadows with no blur, and x,y adjustments. You could try for each side, Top, right, bottom, left. And then use the Make Grid option to distribute these rectangles with 1px padding all around. This is basically like using a center stroked rect though.

Answer (score 2):

As crazy as this sounds, you can use [Apple's spreadsheet app, Numbers](https://www.apple.com/mac/numbers/) to create a table that you can copy and paste into Sketch. I did this example really quick

**Basic workflow**

1. Create a table (do most of the design in here)
   [image: A spiffy table in Numbers]
2. Copy the whole table

   - *EDIT: January 22, 2018*
     [image: Copy as PDF in Numbers screenshot]
   - In the latest version of Numbers, you'll want to highlight the object you want to copy, right click it, and select `Copy as PDF`
3. Go to Sketch
4. Paste your clipboard
   [image: Paste it into Sketch — You can right click and select Paste Here]
   [image: Sketch parses what you copied. It treats it as a PDF]
5. Voilà

**Working in Sketch**

1. We have a table in Sketch! No self adjusting columns though — it's all a manual process from here on out
   [image: Look ma, we have a table in Sketch! No self adjusting columns though — it's all a manual process from here on out]
2. Here's my table with an expanded group list view
   [image: It's all in one group to begin with. Here's my table with an expanded group list view]
3. Some drastic (and horrible looking) changes to show editing capabilities. All the text is left aligned.
   [image: Some drastic (and horrible looking) changes to show editing capabilities. All the text is left aligned.]

Comment: One of those growing pains us early switchers have the pleasure of working around. Good solution.

Comment: Oh how I wish I found this before I painstakingly built it in Sketch... :P

Answer (score 1):

It is true Sketch lacks a table tool, but the work around is to make rectangles styles the way of your liking and duplicating it 12 times.